# Possible to get view size from within a class? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

If a subview of class `MyClass` is added to another view:

```
secondView = MyClass() 
mainView.addSubview(secondView)
```

is it possible to get the subview's dimensions from within the class?

```
secondView = MyClass()
mainView.addSubview(secondView)

class MyClass: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // do whatever the view will need to show
        // *** can I get the view's dimensions here? <----------------------***
        // e.g., draw a diagonal line 
        //  from top left corner to bottom right corner

        // self.bounds and self.frame return (0, 0, 0, 0) here
    }
}
```

Or do they need to be passed in somehow from the view creating it (`mainView`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a view's size reliably within init.  A view's size can change.  Therefore you should either do any drawing you need in drawrect, or if you are using CALAyer, resize your layer in `layoutSubviews` where you will have the bounds of your view and you can then use that to set the frame of your sublayer or subviews.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect
Here is a playground with a simple line example.

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

final class XView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 10
        path.move(to: rect.origin)
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
let v = XView()
v.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 300, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = XView()
```

If you want the fancy version see my GitHub project here:
https://github.com/joshuajhomann/pathmorpher/tree/master/final

Comment: Now I'm even more confused!  (This is a wee bit different from my old Fortran and C days... lol). How would I go about drawing that diagonal line?  Or, say, a filled-in box that was half the height and width and centered in the view?

Comment: I updated the answer with the example.  Also I'm an old C/C++ programmer so if I can do it you can too ;)